# Can't access the links inside wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have installed wordpress using wp toolkit inside my cpanel.Currently I am using vultr's cpanel package to host a website inside the cpanel. I have tool called wp tool kit. I installed wordpress using the wp toolkit. The reason I used the wp tool kit because whenever I try to install the wordpress inside cpanel after fixing wp-config.php it says site can't be reached. I also tried activating WP_DEBUG, true but no errors. That's why I tried installing wordpress using the toolkit. Now I am having an issue after installaing wordpress using tool kit. I can't access to any links inside wp-admin. Like If I try to access on wordpress's settings it says page not found. For all the links it still same issue. First the css wasn't loading then I tried this script:

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

The css started to show up but the main issue is I can't access to any links inside wp-admin. It's very odd problem I have never faced this kind of issue.

This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch ".*\.(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(index.php|wp-login.php|sample.php|general.php)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Those links in the admin section probably point to `.php` files? But not the one mentioned in that second `FilesMatch` directive, so the first one will forbid access simply based on that those files have the suffix `.php`

Comment: what can be the solution for this @CBroe

Comment: Got your point @CBroe Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was in this line:

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Changed to

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This solved the issue

Comment: This was originally meant to prevent your system from being attacked, if a user managed to upload any executable file - like a python script, or a `.exe` on a windows system. Instead of completely switching this from `Deny` to `Allow`, you should rather remove only the suffixes you _want_ (/need) to allow, from that regex pattern.